# Getting Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when parsing JSON array which has data in it in EJS template?

Tags: node.js, ejs

Here is my code to render view and pass data.

```
    var x = '{"products":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}]}';
    res.render('home', {test:x});
```

Here is my code to loop and show data

```
<ul>
<% for(var i=0; i<test.products.length; i++) { %>
    <li>
        <%= test.products[i].id %>
    </li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

I keep getting Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the object to which x refers is a string. you need to parse this as a JSON object using `JSON.parse(test)` using this in your template would look like:

```
for(var i=0; i<JSON.parse(test).products.length; i++)
```

alternatively, when setting the variable x, pass it in as a javascript object:

```
 var x = {"products":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}]};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use **JSON.parse** like this:

```
 res.render('home', {test:JSON.parse(x)});
```

Moreover, You can loop through array of objects like this as well:

```
var products=test.products;
for (var key in products) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined variable `x` as a string, but it should be a javascript object. So you should call `JSON.parse()` to convert its value before passing it to the render engine:

```
var x = '{"products":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}]}';
res.render('home', { test: JSON.parse(x) });
```